# What options should be selected to export a blender object to three.js json file?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, three.js

[image][image]I am trying to export blender object to three.js json file. For this I am selecting "Vertices", "Faces" and "Face Materials" but I am not getting full object in Json file. So what option I should select to export complete object in Json file? Also when I am selecting "Scene" option then blender gets crashed.

Comment: There has been some changes on the three.js side that seem to have broken this process somewhat the last time I checked. I would recommend getting onto the latest version of Blender and trying again.

Comment: @ashish, did you find the solution to that? I am also facing the same problem I the json is showing only white shape. and not the color I have chosen while creating that object.  Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755646/issue-with-getting-colors-in-a-blender-imported-mesh-to-be-shown-using-three-js

Comment: If this is still occurring, this is really a bug in the three.js Blender exporter. I would [report a bug on GitHub](http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/new). As it is, the question seems too broad to answer generically.